# how to refresh react native component when a new data is added to context variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I am trying to build a ticketing app,

this is my page components

```
return (
    <View className="flex-1 m-0 bg-secondary">
      <ActiveTickets
        key={tickets?.length}
        tickets={tickets}
        viewTicket={viewTicket}
      />
      <CreateTicket
        input={input}
        setInput={setInput}
        submitCreateTicket={submitCreateTicket}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

I am trying to have an auto reload ActiveTickets Component after i add a new ticket, but I fail to do it.

```
const { createTicket, tickets, isLoadingTicket, getTickets } =
    useContext(TicketContext);
```

first i load available tickets when the page first load

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthorizeUser() && !isDataLoaded) {
      getTickets(userInfo.data.id, userInfo.data.token.access);
      setIsDataLoaded(true);
    } else {
      router.replace("/");
    }
  }, []);
```

and then after i submit a new ticket (in the same page),
i call the getTickets() function again to set a new tickets list.

```
const submitCreateTicket = () => {
    const roomID = uuid.v4();

    createTicket(
      roomID,
      input.title,
      input.description,
      userInfo.data.id,
      userInfo.data.token.access
    );
    getTickets(userInfo.data.id, userInfo.data.token.access);
  };
```

but my component just doesn't reload (ActiveTickets doesn't reload)

this is my context function:

```
const getTickets = (user_id, token) => {
    setIsLoadingTicket(true);
    axios
      .get(`${BASE_URL}/tickets/${user_id}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
          setTickets(res.data);
          setIsLoadingTicket(false);
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(`ticket reqister error ${e}`);
        setIsLoadingTicket(false);
      });
  };
```

i have tried using useeffect when tickets variable change,

```
useEffect(()=>{
      //do something 
},[tickets]);
```

but it didn't work. I also have tried something like

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthorizeUser() && !isDataLoaded) {
      getTickets(userInfo.data.id, userInfo.data.token.access);
      setIsDataLoaded(true);
    } else {
      router.replace("/");
    }
  }, [getTickets,isDataLoaed,userInfo.data.id]);
```

but it got worse, infinite loop request to server.

Comment: Did you wrap your component with `<TicketContext.Provider>`?

Comment: i have , since i use expo_router, i did it at _layout.js of ticket page

###
import TicketProvider from "../../context/TicketContext";
const _layout = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <TicketProvider>
      <Stack>
       //some stack.screen
      </Stack>
    </TicketProvider>
  );
};

Comment: after i tried with local JSON data, i found out this has to do with async data from getItem, it does not setTickets as soon as I submit ticket. 

Can Anyone help me with the better getItem() solution or i have to use another solution like <flatlist> so i can use refresh data option?

Comment: What does `createTicket` do, does it update the database?

Comment: finally i solved it. The problem is with getTicket when CreateTicket has not finished storing the data. Change all code to await instead of then(), then solved.